# Why is this variable variable not acting properly? PHP

Tags: php

I have this `foreach` loop.

`$i2` looks like this (everytime):

```
$i2 = array(
    'id' => "category['id']"
);
```

And here is a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($i2 as $o3 => $i3)
{
    if (is_array($i3) !== true)
        {
            $new .= "<{$o3}>{$node->$i3}</{$o3}>";
        } else {
            $new .= "<{$o3}>";
            $new .= "</{$o3}>";
        }
    }
}
```

`$node` is a `new SimpleXMLElement($xml_reader->readOuterXML());`. But this is working properly.

The problem is here: if I use `$node->$i3` in order to get XML value of that field - it doesn't work. But if I substitute it for `$node->category['id']` it does. Which seems weird as `$i3` contains `category['id']` and I can check that with debug tools.

I was using this in the previous projects and variable of variable was working fine. Now it doesn't. Why?

@edit

This is what happens before the code:

```
// i move the cursor to the first product tag
while ($xml_reader->read() and $xml_reader->name !== 'product');

        // i iterate over it as long as I am inside of it
        while ($xml_reader->name === 'product')
        {

            // i use SimpleXML inside XMLReader to work with nodes easily but without the need of loading the whole file to memory
            $node = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_reader->readOuterXML());

            foreach ($this->columns as $out => $in)     // for each XML tag inside the product tag
        {
            // ... do stuff
```

Basically this is what happens before the code in question. The `$columns` is an array that enables the configuration of input XML file (keys are Prestashops XML tags and values are names of tags in the user's XML file).

For example:

```
<product>
    <associations>
         <categories>
             <category>
                 <id></id>
             </category>
         <category>
    </associations>
</products>
```

And in input one:

```
<category id="1"></category>
```

So in `$columns`:

```
$columns = ('associations' => array(
    'categories' => array(
        'category' => 'category['id'] // this is what $i3 later is
    )
));
```

I can get to the given point of XML file easily. I get the `category['id']` value and this is what `$i3` is.

Comment: Could you declare a var $node as the one you're using so we can get an idea and try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP preprocessor tries to find the $i3 property on $node. But the object $node has no such property, and then it fails.

Are you sure you use the same syntax when trying to reach the category['id'] property in your previous projects?

You can try this syntax:

```
foreach ($i2 as $o3 => $i3)
{
    if (is_array($i3) !== true)
    {
        $new .= "<{$o3}>" . eval("return \$node->$i3;") ."</{$o3}>";
    } else {
        $new .= "<{$o3}>";
        $new .= "</{$o3}>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I work in Prestashop and if I do this `d($node->$i3);` it will die and give me the var_dump of `$node->$i3`: empty `SimpleXMLElement Object`. If I type `d($node->category['id']);` manually - it returns the same object but with proper value included. I don't understand how `$new` has anything to do with it as it is just a string that I put XML into.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "$node" instead of "$new"

Comment: I bet if you set $i3 = "WHATEVER" you'll find that $node->$i3 will return another SimpleXMLElement Object too.

Comment: Doing `d($i3)` returns `category['id']` properly. I also tried this: `$test = $i3; $node->$test;` but it also fails. While `$node->category['id'];` works just fine.

Comment: @galkowskit Updated my original anser with an alternative syntax. Check it out

Comment: Ok, if it works... upvote my answer and mark it as "valid" ;-) It works because THAT is the way to dinamically build a valid object property accessor in PHP .